# How can I extract parts of this filename in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

In my Excel sheet with column Changeset I am getting the changeset like:

```
C:\ccviews\hgdasdff-9302\dfcsz\ahgrt\kjhssl\ASGHLS@@\main\ajsdkljlat\hahdasdhfk\1\test.txt\sub\hsdaklfl\3
```

I need to use `split` function in a Perl script so that there will be two ouput (input as the above string)

- the part before @@ (e.g-here `C:\ccviews\hgdasdff-9302\dfcsz\ahgrt\kjhssl\ASGHLS`)
- the last character of the string (e.g-here 3)

Comment: Don't start thinking that you need to use some technique. Just tell us what you need to do and show us what you have tried so far. :) http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the two answers already, you can try the following using only split function:

```
$s = 'C:\ccviews\hgdasdff-9302\dfcsz\ahgrt\kjhssl\ASGHLS@@\main\ajsdkljlat\hahdasdhfk\1\test.txt\sub\hsdaklfl\3';

@temp = split/@@/,$s;
$part1 = $temp[0]; # C:\ccviews\hgdasdff-9302\dfcsz\ahgrt\kjhssl\ASGHLS

@temp = split//,$s;
$part2 = $temp[-1]; # 3
```

Answer (score 6):

This sounds too complicated for a regular split, you need an ordinary regex like this:

```
my ($first, $second) = / ^ (.+?) @@ .* (.) $ /x;
```

Comment: This could also be wrapped in a conditional so as to warn if fed any non-matching input, e.g.: `if ( ! /^(.+)?@@.*(.)$/ ) { warn( "Unknown line format: \"$_\"" ); }` - might also be worth adding a quick explanation what the non-greedy expression does, after all you're using the `/x` operator, which allows you to spread the regexp over multiple lines and add comments

Answer (score 3):

From [Regular Expression Mastery](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide070.html) by Mark Dominus:

> ### Randal's Rule
>
> - Randal Schwartz (author of *Learning Perl* [and also a [Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)]) says:
>
> > Use capturing or `m//g` when you know what you want to keep.
> >
> > Use `split` when you know what you want to throw away.
>
> [image: Randal Schwartz]

You know what you want to keep, so use `m//g` as in [Leon Timmermans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318092/need-help-on-split-function-in-perl/2318148#2318148).

Comment: Every gambler knows that the secret to survivin' is knowin' what to throw away and knowin' what to keep

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want, or do you need it all in one statement?

```
 my ($before, $after) = split '@@', $input;
 my $last_char = substr($after, -1, 1);
```